# Why Stored Procedure Data from a class doesn't display in Datagridview on my form

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, ado.net

I'm trying to transfer this code to a class to avoid messy code in a form / user control. I display the data stored procedure successfully in my datagridview when the code is in my form / user control but when I tried to a class it doesn't work anymore. This is the code I'm working with in my class:

My class:

```
public class DisplayCustomer
{
    public void Display_Customer(DataTable dt, DataGridView dgv)
    {     
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCustomer", con))
            {               
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {                        
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
              //    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    dgv = new DataGridView { DataSource = dt };                
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My user control:

```
public partial class ManageCustomer : UserControl
{
    public ManageCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataTable dbdataset;

    private void ManageCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayCustomer dc = new DisplayCustomer();
        dc.Display_Customer(dbdataset, CustomersList);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen: The data doesn't display anymore to datagridview
What i expect: To display the data to datagridview from a class
Results: Nothing Happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems,

1. Use existing Datagridview, instead of create new.

   dgv = new DataGridView { DataSource = dt };

try to do :

```
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

2. Also, if your Datagridview located at UserControl, pass it as

> ref

```
Display_Customer(DataTable dt, ref DataGridView dgv)
```

So, when you call it

```
dc.Display_Customer(dbdataset, ref CustomersList);
```

Let me know if this does not help. I am still on the way to office... So, didn't test the code. :)
try it and update me

Comment: dc.Display_Customer(dbdataset, ref CustomersList);
"Argument 2 may not be passed with the ref keyword"

Comment: when i remove the "new" and use these dgv.DataSource = dt , it worked. Thank you very much